# Angular dependent checkboxes not working as expected

Tags: angular, checkboxlist

I am working on an angular project and i faced some issues when displaying dynamic nested checkboxes in my project.

there is a list of event containing main Categories and each Category contain a subcategory and I want to display the subcategories of the main category outside the for loop of the main categories. i am a rookie so bear with me.

here is the part of my code so far

the component.ts

```
SubCategoryList() {

    this.categoryService.customerSubCategories().subscribe(response => {

      this.childern = response;
      this.listOfOption = this.childern;
      console.log(this.listOfOption);
    })

  }

 filterSubById(id) {

    this.lists = this.listofMainCategories.filter((item:SubCategory) => id.includes(item.mainCategoryId));
    console.log(this.lists);
  }
```

and the component.html

```
    <div class="container" style="margin-left: 25px;"> 

        <h2>Select your Main Category</h2>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of maincat">
        <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
        <nz-checkbox-wrapper style="width: 100%;" (nzOnChange)="filterSubById($event)">
          <div nz-row>
            <div class="row" nz-col nzSpan="8" *ngFor="let data of item.eventMainCategories">
              <label nz-checkbox [nzValue]="data.mainCategoryId" (ngModel)="customer?.customerMainCategories.MainCategoryId">{{data?.mainCategory?.name}} </label>
            </div>
          
          </div>
         
        </nz-checkbox-wrapper>
        
      </ng-container>


        <br><br>
          
        <h2>Select your Sub Category</h2>

        <nz-checkbox-wrapper style="width: 100%;" (nzOnChange)="filterProdById($event)">
             <div class="container">
              <!-- <h3>{{data?.mainCategory?.name}}</h3> -->
            </div>
          <div nz-row>
            <div class="row" nz-col nzSpan="8" *ngFor="let d of lists;">
              <label nz-checkbox [nzValue]="d.id" (ngModel)="customer?.customerSubCategories.subCategoryId">{{d?.name}} </label>
              
            </div>
          
          </div>
         
        </nz-checkbox-wrapper>
      </div>
</div>
```

any solutions?

Comment: `(ngModel)` **not exist**, is `[ngModel]`: one way binding, `[(ngModel)]` two-ways binding or `[ngModel]="variable (ngModelChange)="function($event)"`: two ways binding separate

Comment: i used nzOnChange

Comment: you has a "(ngModel)", that's **not** exist